# RandomForestClassifier Error: Number of features must match input

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm relatively new to sklearn and have been trying to make use of the following code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt

def main():
    #create the training & test sets, skipping the header row with [1:]
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('mypath\data1.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]    
    target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
    test = genfromtxt(open('mypath\data1.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]

    #create and train the random forest
    #multi-core CPUs can use: rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    rf.fit(train, target)

    savetxt(myoutput\data1_output.csv', rf.predict(test), delimiter=',', fmt='%f')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This code runs a random forest classifier on a .csv file containing three columns, the first of which contains labels while the other two contain features.  When running this program I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must  match the input. Model n_features is 2 and  input n_features is 3
```

My initial assumption was that there was a component named n_features that I would need to adjust to my use case.  However, it appears to be more complex than this.  Would anyone be able to explain if and how I could get a .csv of the type I described above to run with this code successfully?

I did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317781/valueerror-while-using-scikit-learn-number-of-features-of-model-dont-match-tha), which suggests the issue is that the code is including my labels as a feature. However, I don't really understand how the solution presented to that problem solves this one and so would greatly appreciate additional explanation.

Comment: It might be more informative if you can upload your csv file somewhere.

Comment: @K.Chen I agree, would it help as much to describe it as consisting of three numeric columns, with headers, where the first column consists of binary (0,1) labels and the other two columns consist of values between 1-10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of your csv file is `(n_examples, 3)`. You split this array into two lists containing the response variables and input variables when you call:

```
target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
```

Thus, `target` is shape `(n_examples, 1)` and `train` is shape `(n_examples, 2)`. Next, you read in the same csv file to test (I don't know why you're using training data to test or why you need to read the file again at this point). Anyhow, this means that `test` is shape `(n_examples, 3)`.

[predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict) takes inputs and produces responses using the model parameters learned through calling `fit`. So `predict` expects to receive a list of input variables of shape `(2,)` or an array of shape `(n_examples, 2)`. You should see where the mismatch is taking place now.

To fix, call `rf.predict(test[1:, 1:])`. This slice takes everything from row 1 onwards and everything from column 1 onwards, skipping the first row assuming it contains header info (you should check that the header is indeed read in) and skipping the first column of every row to skip the response variables for each example.

Of course, since test was read from the same file as your training data, this is equivalent to `rf.predict(train)`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.  Now I realize why this was kind of silly though - the match is going to be perfect without a split test and training set, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As it stands, you are using the same data for both training and test. No split was made.

Comment: Yep, but so I get a perfect classification.  What I should really be doing is bringing in a separate test set now to get actual results, right?

Comment: You should read about training, validation, cross-validation, and testing sets in machine learning. Maybe pick up a text or find a resource online :)

Comment: Probably a good idea :)  I take it what I said is wrong then?

Comment: I don't really want to get into that with such a short response. I'm just saying that the better you know your tools (and the theory behind them), the better you can apply them.