# Model and input features for Random forest don't match

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr

I am trying to perform Machine Learning on the dataset and trying to display the samples and test data. My goal is to later load my IMAGE and test it with the model. Kindly help me in solving the error.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn import ensemble

mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='./')


#Define variables
n_samples = len(mnist.data)
x = mnist.data.reshape((n_samples, -1))# array of feature of 28*28 pixel
y = mnist.target                         # Class label from 0-9 as there are digits

#Create random indices 
sample_index=random.sample(range(len(x)),len(x)/5) #Selecting randomly list of len(x)/5 from the size of x
valid_index=[i for i in range(len(x)) if i not in sample_index]# Selecting the rest of the digits

#Sample and validation images
sample_images=[x[i] for i in sample_index]# 28*28 size of array which was used to classify digits in different classes
valid_images=[x[i] for i in valid_index]

#Sample and validation targets
sample_target=[y[i] for i in sample_index] # digits 0-9
valid_target=[y[i] for i in valid_index]

#Using the Random Tree Classifier
classifier = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=30)

#Fit model with sample data
classifier.fit(sample_images, sample_target)

#Attempt to predict validation data
score=classifier.score(valid_images, valid_target)
print 'Random Tree Classifier:\n' 
print 'Score\t'+str(score)

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, 
                    test_idx=None, resolution=0.02):
    # plot the decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution),
                         np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
```

Till here I am not having any error, but after this line:

```
Z = classifier.predict(np.c_[xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()])
plot_decision_regions(x,y,classifier,test_idx=10)
```

I am having the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 784 and input n_features is 2
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the shape of the np arrays. Try to reshape them. See also here: [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28855470/5025009)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling the function `classifier.predict` you need to pass a new set of testing samples as argument from which your classifier will predict new labels. However, you are passing a meshed matrix, which doesn't make any sense at all. Obviously, your matrix has only 2 columns and the predictor complains as it expects to have 784 columns as your trainset had.

I also recommend you check other areas of your code as I spotted some mistakes (e.g. `len(x)/5` has to be casted as int).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much